# I'm Using NotifydataAdapter But It's Not Working When Value change on database;

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am getting data from server as json. Everything works but `notifyDataSetChanged` is not working.

```
BackGroundTask backGroundtask = new BackGroundtask();
backGroundTask.execute(arrayList);

private class BackGroundWorkeroneSignup extends AsyncTask<List<CheckingDTO>,CheckingDTO, CheckingDTO> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        CheckingDTO check = new CheckingDTO(email_c+"=="+pass_c,email_c,pass_c,email_c,pass_c);
        arrayList.add(checkingDTO);

        adapterActivity = new HistoryAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterActivity);

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CheckingDTO data) {

        super.onPostExecute(data);
        arrayList.clear();

        List<CheckingDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(data);
        adapterActivity = new HistoryAdapter(list);
        adapterActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Weather you used that adapter in ListView?RecyclerView there is no specification in your description.

Comment: You are creating new Adapter Each time . So `notifyDataSetChanged()` is useless in this case . You first need to learn how `notifyDataSetChanged()` works ..

Comment: Please can you guide me how i can use notifyDataSetChanged() in this situation..??

Comment: @BjCreative, I've updated my answer with exp. please read and let me know if you have doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the relevant code that I've sent you in the email.

oncreate method

```
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        adapterActivity = new HistoryAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterActivity);
        backGroundWorkeroneSignup = new BackGroundWorkeroneSignup();
        backGroundWorkeroneSignup.execute(arrayList);
```

background method:

```
 try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("get_request");// this is your array containing data

                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = jobj.getString("id");

                                String email_c =jobj.getString("pick_lat");
                                String pass_c = jobj.getString("pick_lon");

                                checkingDTO = new CheckingDTO(email_c+"=="+pass_c,email_c,pass_c,email_c,pass_c);

                                CheckingDTO check = new CheckingDTO(email_c+"=="+pass_c,email_c,pass_c,email_c,pass_c);
                                arrayList.add(check);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

on PostExecute

```
  adapterActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In First Part Notice the **recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterActivity);**

In Background Mode:

1. when you loop in Array always remember: index starts from 0 therefore it's always less then size of array i.e. `for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)`
2. You should always create new object of Model class in loop for and then add it in loop. There in no need of calling the notifydatasetchanged in loop.

In onPostExecute: we call the notifydatasetchanged only because we've already added all the elements in the list.

hope that explains all of your queries. let me know if you have confusion in any case

Comment: I Tried but Not Working.

Comment: @BjCreative can ya email me your project so that i can look into it. email: sahil.manchanda2@gmail.com

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not required when you already setting a new Adapter instance .. So this answer does not make any sense ..

Comment: @Adm you are right. The problem was slightly different, I've sent the correct answer in the email. Will update here afrer reaching home